# Spring-boot "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" when try to build with java 6

Tags: java, spring, maven

I were doing Spring-boot project with my friend on java 7. It works fine.
However, they decided to put it on java 6 server. So we have to change it.
On my friend's laptop it works fine, but mine didn't. I don't know why it comess to be like this.

I've searched some, and found many root-cause is when you compile with higher version (java 7 for example) and run it on java 6. But what it comes to me, it runs fine when I run the project as Spring-Boot app on STS (which is on java 6 JRE):
[image]

But when I need it to become jar (which I do maven build/maven clean):

[image]

Here is the full log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I wonder what is wrong with this compiler?
Here are some links that I've read:

[Spring Boot - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262788/spring-boot-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

[Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095028/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-openshift)

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

[Why am I getting Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613445/why-am-i-getting-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239086/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/ServletException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938379/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-javax-servlet-servletexception-unsuppo)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106755/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

[Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 but everything is set to JDK 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567514/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-but-everything-is-set-to-jdk-1-6)

I've suspected this has to be with my configuration in STS, or my laptop, because my friend is also using STS, and it worked fine. I have done this suggestion:

[Java 6 Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394456/java-6-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

[image]

But still the error persists.
Any suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: Spring boot is not compatible with outdated java6 version

Comment: Look at this, it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613445/why-am-i-getting-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/38613841#38613841

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be, My Friend didn't change the Java compiler at all. They just change Java Version on Pom.xml:

[image]

And somehow it runs well on our Java 6 Server.

So, in addition with **jens** and **abarisone** comments, Spring-boot and/or it's dependencies need java 7 or more, but when we compile it(with java 7) with target set to java 6, it **compiles**, and **surprisingly** runs on java 6 machine. Can somebody explain it why? is it just luck or what?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the instructions when you want to use Java 6 with Spring Boot:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6

(That said, you really should not be using Java 6 anymore. Even Java 7 has [no more public updates since April 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html))